# Inaccessible cardinals

Tags: set-theory, forcing, large-cardinals

Let $M[G]$ be the full Solovay model, and let HOD be the model of hereditarily ordinal definable sets in $M[G]$.

Is it possible for HOD  not to have an inaccessible cardinal? Does HOD satisfy GCH?

Comment: What are your assumptions on $M$?

Comment: I would like HOD not to have an inaccessible. Is this possible?

Comment: Since you are forcing with a homogeneous poset, HOD does not change, right? So HOD is the HOD of M. Since M contains an inaccessible (by your initial assumption that M[G] is a full Solovay model) then so does its HOD, since inaccessibility relativizes downwards. Whether or not HOD satisfies GCH depends on the specific M you began with. Both options are consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, "the full Solovay model" means that there was $\kappa$ which was inaccessible in $M$ and $G$ is a generic filter for $\operatorname{Coll}(\omega,<\kappa)$. Since this is a homogenous forcing, it doesn't change $\rm HOD$, so $\rm HOD$ of $M[G]$ is the same as in $M$.

If $\kappa$ is inaccessible in $M$ then it is regular and strong limit. In particular in every inner model $\kappa$ is regular, and certainly strong limit (if $\mu<\kappa$ then an inner model can have at most less subsets of $\mu$ than $M$ itself, so certainly not more than $\kappa$).

So if $M[G]$ is "the full Solovay model", then in $\rm HOD$ there is an inaccessible cardinal. Unless of course when you say "the full Solovay model" you don't mean the Levy collapse of an inaccessible cardinal, in which case you should probably state explicitly what you mean.